# Android: invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated after adding consumeContent()

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

I am trying to create an activity to login via http post as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591165/android-http-reponse-code-error. Anyways upon testing I keep getting the following two warnings in my logcat:

> 07-06 11:55:16.934: W/SingleClientConnManager(1049): Invalid use of
>   SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated. 07-06
>   11:55:16.934: W/SingleClientConnManager(1049): Make sure to release
>   the connection before allocating another one.

I did some searching around stackoverflow and I tried adding the following code as people recommned:

```
    response.getEntity().consumeContent();
```

but I am still getting the some warnings. Here is the code to my post request function:

```
private void sendRequest() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            response.getEntity().consumeContent();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
```

What do you guys think I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this issue by following this solution: http://tech.chitgoks.com/2011/05/05/fixing-the-invalid-use-of-singleclientconnmanager-connection-still-allocated-problem/

Hope this solves your problem.